# Get first record by latest date

Tags: sql

Please help complete this sql string? I want to get 1st record from table 1 where `createddate` = most recent/latest.

```
Select TOP 1 * From Table1 Where CreateDate = "latest date??"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `order by`

```
Select TOP 1 * From Table1 order by createddate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

the other way to do it:

```
select * From Table1 order by CreateDate DESC Limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without `TOP`, using subquery:

```
Select * 
  From Table1 
 Where CreateDate = (select max(CreateDate) from Table1)
;
```